# При запуске скрипта из консоли не пишет в файл

Tags: php

Почему, когда запускаю php скрипт из консоли, не пишет в файл, а из браузера пишет?

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$logFileName = "log_price.log";
$fp = fopen($logFileName,'a');
$message = $time." | New records: ".$x." | Deleted records: ".$y." | Changed records :".$z." | Elapsed time: ".substr(($time_end - $time_start),0,8)." s. | Processed: ".($x+$y+$z)." str.\r\n";
fputs($fp, $message);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: при таком форматировании читать невозможно

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте кому из пользователей принадлежит этот файл и права доступа до него.

Чаще всего подобная проблема возникает из-за того что то что работает в броузере скрипт выполняется под одним пользователем, а в консоле под другим.

Comment: сделал полный доступ на файл для всех - все равно не пишет

Comment: Какие-нибудь ошибки хоть выводит ?

Comment: никаких ошибок не выводит
добавил 
if (!fopen($logFileName,'a')) echo "fuck";
if (!fputs($fp, $message)) echo "fuuuuuuck";
трассировать больше нечего, а не ошибок ни лога